# CSV syntax for WP All Import upload without ACF

Tags: plugins, import, csv

I need to import listings into the Listeo theme of Wordpress using WP All Import plugin. All works fine, however, I am unable to import values for custom fields which have a type of Checkbox.

I've tried different syntaxes in the csv file:

```
1
on
['1']
['on']
```

but none seems to work. The field is empty once the upload is completed. Google search provides no answer. I am not using ACF.

Comment: Have you tried to do an export with WP All Export with both checked and unchecked fields, then see what format it creates the entries in and adjusting the import to be the same?

Comment: Yes I did, but I could not get any further. The exported CSV file says just the option value. So if a checkbox has value of 'on' then the exported CSV just says `on`. Exported CSV contains plain text. In case of Multi Checkbox, the exprted CSV says `on|off`. I've tried these options for importing the data, they would not work.